# How can you beat the world record in shooting?

Tags: records, shooting

I'm not expert in the sport of [shooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_sport), but if the world record is calculated by the amount of points, how can you beat a perfect score? You can see the records on [the official site for the London Olympics](http://www.london2012.com/shooting/event/men-50m-rifle-prone/records/index.html), and there is no mentioning of time. So can a score of 600 still be beaten? And what's with the 704.8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the event you mention ([50m Rifle Prone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_metre_rifle_prone)), the 8 best qualifiers shoot in the final event.  In the final event, the scoring zones are divided into tenths, with 10.9 being the maximum score per shot (ten shots are taken).

[image]

The final total is the combination of the qualification and final score.

> The competition is won by the shooter who reaches the highest aggregate score (qualification + final, maximum 709.0).

So, if you shoot in the final, you could hit a perfect 600 (in qualification) and then your final ten could be anything up to 109, meaning a maximum possible of 709.

You note the 704.8 but actually, in the London 2012 games just now, [Sergei Martynov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Martynov_%28sport_shooter%29) won gold with 705.5.

I'll add also that, once someone shoots 709, that will be the maximum world record (and it will be shared by anyone else shooting 709) unless the scoring changes.

For clarity, this is how the shooting is scored:

**Qualification**

- Number of shots : 60
- Score possibilities : 0 to 10 per shot
- Maximum possible score : 60 shots scoring 10 = 600

**Final** (Top 8 qualifying shooters)

- Number of shots : 10
- Score possibilities : 0 to 10.9 per shot
- Maximum possible score : 10 shots scoring 10.9 = 109

**Final Score**

- Qualifying Score + Final Score = Total Score
- 600 + 109 = 709

Comment: good extension. Why 10.9 max in final, and 10 in qualification?

Comment: In qualification there are clear zones to hit.  I've added an image above.  You either score 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or 10 depending on which concentric circle you hit.  In the final, these zones are further divided into tenths.  So, the central "10" ring is divided into ten tenths: 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9.  It's done to score the final at a more accurate level.